# Reverse order bar chart without reversing axis values

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I am trying to create a bar chart in excel in reverse order categories.

The following does the trick:

```
chart.set_y_axis({ 'reverse': True})
```

But then the the x-axis values are on top of the chart, while I want to keep them on the bottom.

I tried to reverse the order then move the x-axis labels via:

```
chart.set_x_axis({ 'label_position': 'low'})
```

This does not seem to do anything. That is strange, because if  I don't reverse the y-axis and just set the x-axis position to 'high", then it does move the x-axis values to the top. So I don't know why it won't also move it to the bottom.

How can I reverser the order of categories in an excel bar chart, while keeping the x-axis values at the bottom?

Example code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Some sample data to plot.
list_data = [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]

# Create a Pandas dataframe from the data.
df = pd.DataFrame(list_data)

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
excel_file = 'column.xlsx'
sheet_name = 'Sheet1'

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file, engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name)
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]

# Create a chart object.
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'bar'})

# Reverse Order
chart.set_y_axis({ 'reverse': True,
                   'label_position': 'low'
                   })
# Try and fail to get x-axis values on bottom instead of top
chart.set_x_axis({ 'label_position': 'low'
                   })
# Configure the series of the chart from the dataframe data.
chart.add_series({
    'values':     '=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$8',
})

# Insert the chart into the worksheet.
worksheet.insert_chart('D2', chart)

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

P.s. Not sure if such comments are allowed here, but xlsxwriter is the best thing since sliced bread!

Comment: Would it be possible to see an image of the chart currently produced by your code and one of the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the type of output that you want in Excel (and XlsxWriter) you need to set the crossing point for the axis using the "Axis crosses at maximum category" option.

With XlsxWriter you can do it using the axis `crossing` parameter. Like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Some sample data to plot.
list_data = [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]

# Create a Pandas dataframe from the data.
df = pd.DataFrame(list_data)

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
excel_file = 'column.xlsx'
sheet_name = 'Sheet1'

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file, engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name)
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]

# Create a chart object.
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'bar'})

# Reverse Order
chart.set_y_axis({'reverse': True,
                  'crossing': 'max'})

# Configure the series of the chart from the dataframe data.
chart.add_series({'values': '=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$8'})

# Insert the chart into the worksheet.
worksheet.insert_chart('D2', chart)

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

**Output**:

[image]